# hide nav bar on scroll down and show on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide my top nav bar when scrolls down and show when scrolls up like this [website](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) nav bar. currently, I am using this code but it's not working properly, it works when scrolling down but doesn't when scrolling up.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

// Hide #main-nav on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#main-nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .MagicMenu-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('#main-nav').slideDown(500);
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#main-nav').slideUp(500);
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything special if you want to hide the navbar on scroll down. Just don't set your navbar position to static in css. May be you can provide a fiddle on your code for better understanding.

Comment: Your fiddle is not working

Comment: sorry i just posted the javascript without css and html

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
  background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
  top: 0; /* Stay on top */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
}

/* Style the navbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

When the user scrolls down, hide the `navbar`. When the user scrolls up, show the `navbar`:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

I used the JavaScript below for my code since I had a checkbox as a Hamburger Icon that toggles the `nav` bar when the icon is clicked. when on mobile the user presses the hamburger icon, `nav` bar is displayed , but when he scrolls down, the `nav` bar is hidden, when he scrolls back up, the `nav` bar comes back into display:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("check").checked = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no need for `setInterval(function() { ...` as you're executing the function non-stop even when the user is not scrolling, replace it with an `eventListener` for the scroll,

your `#main-nav` is only sliding up and down, you need to change it's position according to the scroll to make i visible when it slides down,

try to avoid jquery animation and use css transition for the effect when possible, it's good for performance,

here's an example ( without jQuery ), tweak it to your needs :

```js
let nav = document.querySelector('#nav');
let lastScrollTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {  // listen for the scroll 
  var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (st > lastScrollTop) 
    nav.style.opacity = 0; // hide the nav-bar when going down
  else 
    nav.style.opacity = 1; // display the nav-bar when going up
  
  lastScrollTop = st;

  nav.style.top = `${st}px`; // set the position of the nav-bar to the current scroll
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

</div>
```